# Two or more icons are displayed on taskbar for Visual Studio 2015 in multi-window mode

Tags: visual-studio-2015, taskbar, multi-window

I have two displays and using VS 2015 in multi-window mode (i.e., separate tabs on different screens). 
VS 2013 always showed only one icon on taskbar which was very comfortable but VS 2015 shows one icon per separate window. This drives me nuts!

I tried to find a setting to turn off this behavior but no results. Googling did not help much as well.

BTW, I am using Win Server 2008 R2.

Did somebody find how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can enable the **Floating tab wells always stay on top of the main window** option in Visual Studio 2015 options to disable additional taskbar icons from floating tabs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you mean this:

[image]

then i set it here:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in my case: http://i.imgur.com/IrO3USm.png (two icons for one opened solution)

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I am running Win Server 2008 R2 on my virtual machine, not Win 7. Question text is updated.